# How do I make a negative amount in form field produce a warning error

Tags: javascript

I have a .html form field that when it changes to a negative number, it Warns users that this field needs to be a positive number ?

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What did you try to achieve this?

Comment: Cool feature. Never seen that before. Can you show me how you did it?

Comment: It was a question ! I have seen it before when a field is left empty, But not the way I want it.

Comment: at least post some code you've written trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the onblur event handler of the html field, write javascript function to check if the value is a number. If it is, check whether it is less than 0. If yes, write css to make field border red or display a warning.

Or,
You can use a field input type number with min value set in html5.

```
<input type="number" name="f1" id="f1" min="0">
```

Comment: I used <input name="kWh" type="text" min="0"  /> If I change "text" to "number" the field does not work at all.

Comment: Are you using  <!Doctype html> on your html document. Do you have a input type="submit" button. Is your number input type and submit button inside a form?

Comment: @Demon it should work but only if you enter numbers. text does not work if the input type is "number"

Answer (score -1):

```
WOW has it been this long, time flys.
```

This is the Java code "alert" Text that should be shown in a Pop-up tab.

**Java Code: start;**

Excess_kWh_DayCalc = Daily_kWh_HarvestedCalc - Daily_kWh_Consumption;
if (Excess_kWh_DayCalc <0)
alert("Excess Energy Field needs to remain Positive for calculator accuracy, So Increase the Energy Generated or Reduce the Energy Consumed!");

**Java Code: FINISH.**

**FYI:** The **Excess_kWh_DayCalc** is the html Form Cell Name.